# Python is not playing sound but it finishes the program successfully without errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-playsound

I am trying to play sound in Python. When I run my code, it finishes successfully but the audio is not played by my computer.

I have tried with all the libraries like playsound, simpleaudio, pydub and kivy core audio.

Sample code I tried is:

```py
from playsound import playsound

playsound('myfile.wav')
```

Comment: Maybe playsound() can play only mp3 or different files?

Answer (score 0):

As i think it should work, check either your audio file (maybe it's empty) or check your audio drivers and audio output.

OR, You can try

**pip install playsound**
one more time

Comment: it plays when opened with vlc media player

Comment: which OS you are using rn

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: try **sudo pip install playsound** one more time

Comment: i tried that it shows requirement already satisfied,i tried on reinstalling the playsound.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, use the complete path:

```py
from playsound import playsound
playsound(r"C:\some\path\sound.mp3") # the "r" is necessary, or else your code wont work!
```